# Accessing session variable in Razor Layout?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When i write code in my layout page

Profile

@Session["iname"].ToString();

I got this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

i tried
   @HttpContext.Current.Session["iname"].ToString()
but not working

Comment: `@Session["iname"]` is null. Did you set it anywhere? In any case I'd generally recommend passing data to the view through the view model and letting your controller pull it from the session.

Comment: institute ins = (from I in db.institutes
                             where I.uid == id
                             select I).FirstOrDefault();
            iimage im =     (from Im in db.iimages
                            where Im.uid == id && Im.isLogo == 1
                            select Im).FirstOrDefault();
            Session["iid"] = ins.Id;
            Session["iname"] = ins.Title;
            Session["ilogo"] = im.imgpath;

Comment: Can any body tel me diff types of accessing session variables in layout??

Answer (score 6):

you can do this in the design

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@if (Context.Session.GetString("iname") != null){}
```

Answer (score 4):

This means that there is nothing with the key `"iname"` in Session. `Null` check this before you use `ToString`:

```
@if(Session["iname"] != null)
{
    Session["iname"].ToString();
}
```